# amp-carousel 0.2 shows the error "startLayout called but not LAYOUT_SCHEDULED currently: 2" when changing the screen resolution

Tags: javascript, amp-html, amp-img

When the screen resolution is changed, the console displays the message `startLayout called but not LAYOUT_SCHEDULED currently: 2` and amp-img element is returned. If you stop and reload the page, the error disappears until you change the screen resolution again.

This only happens in **amp-carousel version 0.2**, in version 0.1 everything works without errors, but the sliders transition is too fast.
The error appears for dynamic attribute value ( if `width = "auto"` or if `layout = "responsive"` and so on ) with **autoplay** and **type="slides"**.

For example:

```
<amp-carousel
  type="slides"
  layout="fixed-height"
  height="300"
  width="auto" 
  delay="2000"
  autoplay>
 ...
```

or

```
<amp-carousel
  type="slides"
  layout="responsive"
  height="300"
  width="600" 
  delay="2000"
  autoplay>
 ...
```

What can I do to fix this problem or is it a bug with the amp version?